# How to insert at the very left of the line in vim?

Tags: vim

Imagine I am editing this code in vim, and wish to comment out the `bar();` line:

```
while (foo()) {
   bar();
   baz();
}
```

If I press `I#` while on that line, I get this:

```
while (foo()) {
   #bar();
   baz();
}
```

However, our coding standards say I should have done this:

```
while (foo()) {
#   bar();
   baz();
}
```

I can work around this by pressing `0i#` instead (or even putting `map I 0i` in my .vimrc for a more permanent fix) but this is not repeatable with `.` as it just repeats the `i` rather than the `0i`.

Many other editors have options to make Home not be "smart" and just go to column 0 rather than trying to work with the indentation. I've tried searching the docs, but have drawn a blank — is there a way to do this in vim?

Alternatively, is there a way to make the bound command atomic, so that repeating it with `.` repeats the whole thing rather than the last command of the bound sequence?

Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, what coding standards recommend that `#` comments be placed in the first column? That makes it look like an old-school preprocessor directive on a C compiler that doesn't support `#` starting anywhere but the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `gI` instead of `I`.

From `:help gI` :

```
                                                        gI                
gI                      Insert text in column 1 [count] times.  {not in Vi}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `gI` command. In the excellent and comprehensive help, you would have found that just below the entry for `:help I`.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a commenting plugin like [commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) (which I use), [Nerd Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter), [EnhCommentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23), [tComment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim), ..., [etc](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). However from what I can tell only EnhCommentify has an option to respect indention or not (`g:EnhCommentifyRespectIndent`).

If you already have a commenting plugin that you like and it doesn't work the way you like I suggest you open an issue via the plugin's issue tracker and request the option.

If you want to skip the plugin then you use these quick n' dirty mappings inspired by commentary:

```
nnoremap <expr> gcc getline('.') =~ '^#' ? '0"_xw' : "gI#\<esc>w"
xnoremap <expr> gc ':norm! ' . (getline("'<") =~ '^#' ? '0"_x' : "gI#") . "\<cr>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the home key to go to the beginning of the line and then insert

Comment: Thanks, but that only works on some systems — for example, it just goes to the start of the scroll buffer on a Mac. Also, my aim was to make the single-key shortcut work the way I needed, rather than have to press two keys every time and lose the repeat command ability.

Comment: @JohnYeates FYI (I know you already have a solution that works) `0` will take you to the first column, so an alternative to assigning a mapping to `gI` would have been to assign it to `0i`.